# SELECT NOT IN goes extremely slow while separate SELECTS do not take long

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, select

I am using a function to return all the dates between a `startdate` and an `enddate`. The function works fine and fast (around 300 records returned).

```
 SELECT thedate FROM dbo.ExplodeDates('20141216','20151011')
```

In another table, I am checking if my reports are received so I get distinct values of my report date. This query also takes less than a second to complete (around 200 records returned).

```
SELECT DISTINCT(reportdate) FROM dbo.MyReportTable
```

But when I use these two like the following, the query becomes unresponsive:

```
SELECT thedate FROM dbo.ExplodeDates('20141216','20151011')
WHERE thedate NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT(reportdate) FROM dbo.MyReportTable)
```

Here is the code to `ExplodeDates` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ExplodeDates](@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime)
returns table as
return (
with 
 N0 as (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,N1 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N0 t1, N0 t2)
,N2 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N1 t1, N1 t2)
,N3 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N2 t1, N2 t2)
,N4 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N3 t1, N3 t2)
,N5 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N4 t1, N4 t2)
,N6 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N5 t1, N5 t2)
,nums as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as num FROM N6)
SELECT DATEADD(day,num-1,@startdate) as thedate
FROM nums
WHERE num <= DATEDIFF(day,@startdate,@enddate) + 1
);
GO
```

Comment: you're using an `in` operator.  They are notorious for being slow.  adding a subquery to it, and it's not at all surprising that it's going to crawl.  Not sure of the syntax off the top of my head, but you might want to look at using a `Right Join` or so in place of the subquery.  Another option might be using `Where Not Exists`.  This also might be slow, but should still be an improvement on what you're using right now.

Comment: Why can't you just use a `WHERE` clause, with something like `theDate > @startDate AND theDate < @endDate`?  You'd still have to use `DISTINCT(theDate)` but I don't understand the need for the the `ExplodeDates` function.

Comment: @user2366842 how will it look like using a `RIght Join`? It is returning millions of rows here.

Comment: Try something more like this instead.  I'm not entirely positive this syntax is correct, thus I'm not marking it down as an answer, but this might be better than what you have (if it runs...) 

`SELECT thedate FROM dbo.ExplodeDates('20141216','20151011') ed
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select reportdate rd from dbo.MyReportTable rt
inner join ed.thedate = rt.reportdate)`

Only doubt in my mind with this working, is I don't often use functions within my queries...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can use temp table and it helps with performence. For example:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#TMP') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #TMP END
GO

SELECT thedate INTO #TMP FROM dbo.ExplodeDates('20141216','20151011')

SELECT thedate from #TMP
WHERE thedate NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT(reportdate) FROM dbo.MyReportTable)
```

You can try with #TMP2 for MyReportTable if it will help with performence.
Remember to remove this table after all using:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#TMP') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #TMP END
GO
```

Comment: Yes, I will eventually switch to a temp table solution if I didn't find anything better, but the question is why should a comparison between 300 and 200 records which will be around 60000 should take such a long time and cause my management studio to become unresponsive?

Comment: As I've stated in my initial comment, it's because of your `In` operator.  If you're using it for anything more than 1 or 2 values, it's usually not the right choice.  It does a full scan of the results for each record in the `In` condition, so if your subquery is returning 50,000 results, it's scanning through your ENTIRE result set 50,000 times.

Answer (score 0):

Just an educated guess without the details like difference in query plans, but instead of the function you could just create a date table, with one row per day. That most likely works a lot better than a function with a dynamic tally table that has to calculate huge amount of dateadds every time

Also you might want to test fetching the dates into a temp. table and using that in the SQL, and most likely not exists works better than not in.